# what is the regular expression for URL rewriting in my case?

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

i have a search engine and i want search queries' URLs to be more human readable.
the engine support search in selected categories, lets say cat1 ,cat2 and cat3

if the user selected cat1 and cat3 to search in, the URL will looks like:
`mysite.com/search.php?q=productname&cats=cat3,cat1`

i want the rewrite url to look like the following form:
`mysite.com/productsearch/cat1-cat3/productname`

is it possible to rewrite this rule and replace `-` with `,`?

Comment: Do you want the order of `cat3` and `cat1` to be switched, or was that a typo?

Comment: no ,the order in both original and the rewrite URL is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/search.php\?q=\(.*\)&cats=\(cat[0-9]\),\(cat[0-9]\)/productsearch\/\2-\3\/\1/g'`

should be close...

Parsing this:

"find the stuff that follows "search.php?q=", up to "&", and put it in buffer 1

"find the two things that follow "cats=" of the form "cat followed by a digit" and are separated by a comma - put them into buffers 2 and 3"

"replace the whole thing with `productsearch/(buffer 2)-(buffer 3)/(buffer 1)`"

It may not be perfect but it should be really close... Test output:

```
echo 'mysite.com/search.php?q=productname&cats=cat3,cat1' | sed 's/search.php\?q=\(.*\)&cats=\(cat[0-9]\),\(cat[0-9]\)/productsearch\/\2-\3\/\1/g'
mysite.com/productsearch/cat3-cat1/productname
```

Comment: I just realized you probably want to use Apache's mod_rewrite syntax... so this won't work for you. I will give it another shot later in the day. Meanwhile maybe someone can get inspiration from my thoughts above...